# Decomposition of Stress Components

Tags: condensed-matter, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

[image]
When we are separating the stress matrix into two,mainly into hydrostatic and deviatoric the diagonal elements are the one which are only supposed to be affected then why are we writing a prime symbol on top of every non diagonal stress component?

Comment: Because how else would you refer all-at-once to the entity called the deviatoric stress tensor.

Comment: @ChetMiller Just another forerunner to the same concept.Tell me how $\sigma_{11}$ and $\sigma_{xx}$ are different?I tend to interchange them at times.

Comment: @ChetMiller However the value of the non diagonal elements in deviatoric will not change right.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: sometimes 11 or 1 is reserved for the maximum principal component.